# What is the story behind the phrase 'as it were'? Where did it come from?

Tags: idioms, catch-phrases, expressions

This is a question my High School English teacher could not answer 20-odd years ago and every time I encounter it, it bugs me. I only know what it means in terms of other phrases such as 'per se'.

I have a general idea what it means, but I can't really wrap my head around it. 'As it were' when exactly?

Does anyone know the origin?

Comment: It was pretty archaic:"God brought them out of Egypt; he hath as it were the strength of an unicorn. Taken from Psalms which was written approx. 500-600B.C.

Comment: @Third Idiot, they probably weren't translated into English until a bit later. :)

Comment: My thanks to all. I sleep better tonight now that this is finally resolved for me.

Comment: It's one of those phrases that makes my skin crawl. I've noticed it is used a lot by pseudo intellectuals.

Answer (score 9):

The form *were* is a **past subjunctive**, and it is used in a construction that is common in hypothetical situations:

> He would kill me if he *were* able.
>
> She behaves *as* [would be fitting / etc.] if she *were* upper class.

The phrase is theoretically short for *as [it would be if] it were [so]*, though it is uncertain whether that is really where it came from.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (2nd ed.) has its earliest quote from circa 1386:

> **As it were:** *as if it were so, if one might so put it, in some sort:* a parenthetic phrase used to indicate that a word or statement is perhaps not formally exact though practically right.
>
> - c1386 *Chaucer Nun's Pr. T. 26* She was as it were a maner deye.
> - 1399 *Langl. P. Pl. C. ix. 22* Ich wolde
>   a-saye som tyme for solas, as hit
>   were.
> - 1531 *Elyot Gov. (1834) 211* It draweth
>   a man as it were by violence.
> - 1579 *E. K. in Spenser's Sheph. Cal.
>   Mar. 11 Gloss.,* The messenger, and as
>   it were, the forerunner of springe.
> - 1692 *E. Walker Epictetus' Mor. (1737)
>   xxii,* You're as it were the Actor of a
>   Play.
> - 1711 *Steele Spect. No. 32 31* She has
>   thought fit, as it were, to mock
>   herself.
> - 1881 *Buchanan God & Man I. 124* She
>   took him at once, as it were, into her
>   confidence.

Comment: or 'so-called', 'soi-disant', 'air-quotes', pointing out explicitly a metaphor or a not-strictly-literal interpretation

Answer (score 4):

Webster's 3rd New Int'l Dictionary gives its meaning as:

> **as it were**: as if it were so : in a manner of speaking <her triumph, *as it were*, did not last long>

*The Oxford English Dictionary* dates its first written usage by Chaucer c. 1386.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *Oxford English Dictionary*, it's quite an ancient phrase that emerged from an archaic form of the subjunctive mood:

> a. Introducing a supposition, expressed by the subjunctive mood: As if, as though. *arch*.
>
> 1135    *Anglo-Saxon Chron*.,   Uuard þe sunne suilc als it uuare thre niht ald mone.

As the definition above suggests, a rough modern English equivalent to this original use might be 'as if,' as in 'he reeled as if hit by a sledgehammer.'

The *OED* dates its current sense to c1400:

> c1400  (1387)    Langland *Piers Plowman* (Huntington HM 137) C. ix. l. 22   Ich wolde a-saye som tyme for solas, as hit were.
>
> c1405  (1390)    Chaucer *Nun's Priest's Tale* (Hengwrt) (2003) l. 26   She was as it were a maner deye.
>
> 1531    T. Elyot *Bk. named Gouernour* iii. xi. sig. ci,   It draweth a man as it were by violence.

These uses are clearly different from the original, and closer to the modern use, but it's not hard to imagine a plausible narrative to explain how they might have arisen from the original.

Comment: As if. A rough pragmatic equivalent perhaps, in formal English, but their syntax is quite different: _as if_ always heads a tensed clause, while _as it were_ **is** a clause, and a parenthetical one at that. Only in very informal English does one find parenthetical _as if_ functioning this way.

Comment: @JohnLawler, sorry, I take it that you disagree with something I say above, but I can't quite tell what... could you clarify?

Comment: Your last sentence: "A rough grammatical equivalent in modern English might be 'as if,' as in 'he reeled as if hit by a sledgehammer.'" Pragmatically equivalent and semantically equivalent in some ways, but '_grammatically_ equivalent' is precisely what it's **not**. That's all.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I wasn't trying to say "as if" in modern usage is equivalent to "as it were" in modern usage, as exemplified by the quotations from c1400 on. I was trying to say that "as if" in modern usage is roughly equivalent to "as it were" as used in the first quote from 1135, which I've seen rendered "the sun became such as if it were a three-nights’ old moon." But perhaps that rendering is wrong, or perhaps I'm misinterpreting things...

Comment: It's just that I'm extremely paranoid about the use of the word _**grammar**_ to refer to semantics, or pragmatics, or spelling, or punctuation, or gods know what else, when what it means -- and "grammar" is in the name of the SE -- is actually something completely different.

Comment: @JohnLawler, well, I completely understand you there. I guess I'll change it just to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought the phrase was derived from *as it were so* and both [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_it_were) and [textdriven.com](http://mind.textdriven.com/archive/10/as-it-were) seem to support this story.

> Probably a truncation of "as it were so".

And

> “As it were”—a curious, parenthetic phrase. As if it were so. A phrase used “to indicate that a word or statement is perhaps not formally exact though practically right”

I'm afraid that's as far as you're going to get. Unless someone has better ideas?

Answer (score -2):

to my mind, the phrase 'as it were' is synonymous with that of 'as is the case' or 'as is the actual case'; or of 'as happens to be the case' or 'as happens to be the actual case'.

Comment: In general, we encourage answerers to support their arguments with references to external authorities or evidence.  In other words, "*to my mind*" is not generally speaking enough to warrant posting an answer.

Comment: This does not explain the origin of the phrase, which is what the question asks for. They already know the meaning in terms of other phrases.